# How to split values into different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what I have

```
|name|surname|job       |
|Mike|Watson |programmer|
|Josh|White  |manager   |
```

And what I need to make:

```
|name|surname|programmer|manager|
|Mike|Watson |programmer|null   |
|Josh|White  |null      |manager|
```

What is the easiest way to do that, maybe without using addtional temporary tables?

Regards

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of a `case` expression:

```
select name, surname,
       (case when job = 'manager' then job end) as manager,
       (case when job = 'programmer' then job end) as programmer
from table t;
```

Note that you need to write specific logic for each column.  You cannot use SQL to add a variable number of columns, based on the contents in the rows.  So, if you added "`intern'`, you would have to add logic for this value.

It is also unclear to me why you want a column that takes on either `NULL` or the name of the column.  Presumably, you have a good reason.

Comment: that's what I was looking for! thx!
the reason is that I have to provide data for old and badly designed app

Comment: Actually, `CASE` is an expression.. :)

Comment: @NickyvV . . . That is how the SQL Server describes it, so I changed the word.  I'm sure I'll still call it a "statement" in the future, but maybe I'll learn.  ;)

Comment: Well, it says here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx it is an Expression :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use case and group by or pivot method to solve it.